# How do I use one object from one function in another function in the same class

Tags: python, loops, class, object

I want to use `"img"` of `browse_file()` in `grey_scale()`. 
I am able to use `band_count(type Int)` but when I am trying to use `"img"` in `grey_scale()`, I'm getting the following error:

```
the type of "img" is class 'spectral.io.bilfile.BilFile'
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "main.py", line 50, in grey_scale
view = imshow(img,(bandGrey,))`
NameError: global name 'img' is not defined`
```

My code:

```
def browse_file(self,MainWindow):
    file = str(QtGui.QFileDialog.getOpenFileName(self,"Select Directory"))
    img = envi.open(file)       #load image to img object.
    band_info = str(img.read_band) 
    band_count = int((band_info.split(start))[1].split(end)[0])
    view = imshow(img,(1,0,0))

def grey_scale(self):
    bandGrey = self.spinBox_grey_band.value()
    print bandGrey      #working
    view = imshow(img,(bandGrey,))  #error
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The point of local variables is that they only exist within the function, so you can't do this by definition.

Often, the answer is to pass the variable's value around. For example, `browse_file` could return `img` to its caller, and that caller could keep it around and then pass it into `grey_scale` later.

Another option is to use a class to hold state. These functions seems to be methods of a class already (based on the `self` parameter), so there's a good chance this is the right design here. Just replace every `img` in both functions with `self.img`, and now this isn't a local variable, it's a member of the instance. Every method called on the same instance will have access to the same value. But if you create multiple instances of the same class, each instance will have its own `img`.

Comment: thanx @abarnet.  self.img worked for me. is there more efficient or modular way to do that ?

Comment: @vijaysingh I don't understand your question. I can't think of anything relevant you could mean by "modular". As for "efficient", I can think of a few things, but I doubt any of them are what you're thinking, and even if I'm wrong about that, I couldn't answer without knowing which one it is.

Comment: @vijaysingh But this is perfectly _idiomatic_. It's the normal way to store state that belongs to each instance of some class, and really it's the main reason we have classes in the first place. This is only wrong if `img` isn't supposed to be something that belongs to each instance of the class. (For example, if you're going to have 100 of these objects but only one of them ever calls `browse_file` and they're all supposed to share the resulting `img`, then it should be a class attribute or a module global instead.)

Comment: sorry, don't mind . may be i am thinking too much . thanx for your reply.
but, is there a way to use it without making it a class variable ?

Comment: like if other instance of img can have different values in different functions

Comment: @vijaysingh I don't understand what you mean. If you want different values in different functions (on the same object), you presumably want them to have different names, so you can refer to those different values in some way. And you can have multiple attributes with different names, of course, just like you have have multiple local variables with different names.

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you need to make `img` an instance attribute, so that it gets "saved" in `self` between calls to `browse_file` and `grey_scale`:

```
def browse_file(self,MainWindow):
    file = str(QtGui.QFileDialog.getOpenFileName(self,"Select Directory"))
    img = envi.open(file)       #load image to img object.
    band_info = str(img.read_band) 
    band_count = int((band_info.split(start))[1].split(end)[0])
    view = imshow(img,(1,0,0))
    self.img = img

def grey_scale(self):
    bandGrey = self.spinBox_grey_band.value()
    print bandGrey      #working
    view = imshow(self.img,(bandGrey,))  #error
```

This means, of course, that you need to ensure that `browse_file` is called before `grey_scale`, so that `self.img` is defined before it is used.

Comment: actually i am using one function show_image(). that calls grey_scale() on click event of a button .
def show_image(self,MainWindow):  #works with button show.
        #view = imshow(img,(1,0,0))
               if(self.radioButton_greyscale.isChecked() ):
            self.grey_scale().
how do i do it ?

Answer (score 0):

You need to return the `img` from the function `browse_file()`

Then create a new vaiable from the function.

next add the img to the list of arguments in grey_scale()

```
def browse_file(self,MainWindow):
    file = str(QtGui.QFileDialog.getOpenFileName(self,"Select Directory"))
    img = envi.open(file)       #load image to img object.
    band_info = str(img.read_band) 
    band_count = int((band_info.split(start))[1].split(end)[0])
    view = imshow(img,(1,0,0))
    return img

img = browse_file(self,MainWindow)

def grey_scale(self, img):
    bandGrey = self.spinBox_grey_band.value()
    print bandGrey      #working
    view = imshow(img,(bandGrey,))  #error 

grey_scale(img)
```

you can reuse img inside the class.

If you wish to use the img variable outwith of the class, you can either make it global

```
global img
img = browse_file(self,MainWindow)
```

or create a variable from the class.

ie.

```
img = class_object.browse_file(MainWindow)
```

Comment: I am using browse_file to just browse the file. then i want to use " img " in different functions. so, do i need to call each time when i want to use " img "?

Comment: as soon as you create `img` you can use the variable in different functions no problem..

Comment: Thanx , it will help me while using it in other module.

Comment: If you have a correct answer. Please select the green tick so future users can find an answer.   Good luck